# MATLAB: Creating surface from point cloud with Delaunay

Tags: matlab, triangulation, delaunay

In MATLAB, I load the following point cloud:

```
load tetmesh
```

This loads `X` and `tet` into the workspace.  I thus perform a scatterplot, and this is what the result looks like:

```
scatter3(X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3))
```

[image: blah]

I also invoke `trisurf` in the following fashion, and it gives me:

```
trisurf(tet, X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3))
```

[image: this]

If i don't use `tet`, and try to build my own connectivity list with Delaunay:

```
tri = delaunay(X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3))
trisurf(tri, X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3))
```

I get this:

[image: blah]

This isn't anywhere near the image generated with `tet`. The tetrahedrons generated also don't fulfill the Delaunay criterion as far as I can tell.

My question is this: Is there a possibility to generate a connectivity list like `tet` just from `X`?

Comment: Compare `tet` and `tri`.  Are there any differences in the connectivity list?  Are they in a different order perhaps in comparison to each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Delaunay triangulation of a point-set is guaranteed to fill its convex hull *by definition*. As such, the output shown is exactly as expected. Additionally, all elements in the tessellation *will* satisfy [the Delaunay 'empty-sphere' criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).

The process of reconstructing a surface given a set of points is known as *surface reconstruction*. Such a problem is not typically well-posed, with a variety of non-unique reconstructions typically possible for a given point-set. A number of heuristic approaches have been developed, and a package such a [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) may be useful to you in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
load tetmesh
coeff = 1;
tri = triangulation(boundary(X, coeff), X);
trisurf(tri); colormap(jet);
```

Three different values of `coeff` are shown below:

[image: coeff 1]
[image: coeff 0.5]
[image: coeff 0.1]